# iphone apns cert(.p12) file expired

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

my app use apns to send notifications, after one year, the cert file had expired,
but my CSR(.certSigningRequest) cannot been found, here is the question.

If i create a new CSR file, and new ios aps_distribution, do i need submit a new 
app to AppStore?

Answer (score 2):

**No you don't.**
You certificate is only used to access Apple's APNS from your server (or your PUSH service provider's). Your app will not expire.

**Edit:**

> i use javapns-2.2 to send notification to my app, when use
>   aps_development cert, i can receive the message, but when i use the
>   new created aps_distribution, it shows send success, but my app cannot
>   receive msg, do you know why? or do you know how to test production
>   push?

As [Aanabidden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4019079/aanabidden) stated, don't forget that you can't use a production certificate for development and a development certificate for production. Apple's servers are separated for those schemes and an invalid certificates won't work.

Comment: i use javapns-2.2 to send notification to my app, when use aps_development cert, i can receive the message, but when i use the new created aps_distribution, it shows send success, but my app cannot receive msg, do you know why? or do you know how to test production push?

Comment: If APNS responded with success, it should work. Try again in a few minutes maybe ?

Comment: @chopper make sure you have installed app from app store and not a development app

Comment: @Aanabidden U are right, I found, device token is different between development and production.

Comment: I edited my answer to include @Aanabidden precisions.